# What will be the correct SQL Statement for inserting into a SQL Server table having Identity and timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a table ...

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects 
           where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[ADDRESS_BOOK]') 
             and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
    drop table [dbo].[ADDRESS_BOOK]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ADDRESS_BOOK] 
(
   [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
   [FIRST_NAME] [varchar] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
   [LAST_NAME] [varchar] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
   [CONTACT_NOS] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
   [MODIFIED_BY] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
   [MODIFIED_TIME] [timestamp] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My question is what should be the SQL statement for inserting data into this table ?

I tried

```
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        With sb
            .Append("SET IDENTITY_INSERT ADDRESS_BOOK ON ")
            .Append("INSERT INTO ADDRESS_BOOK(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,")
            .Append("CONTACT_NOS,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_TIME) VALUES(NULL,")
            .Append("'" & TbFName.Text & "','" & TbLName.Text & "','" & TbContactNos.text & "','" & TbUser.Text & "',NULL)")
            .Append(" SET IDENTITY_INSERT ADDRESS_BOOK OFF")
        End With
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But it is giving me error...

`Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'MY_DB.dbo.ADDRESS_BOOK'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: First of all - read up on **SQL Injection** and **stop concatenating** together your SQL statements!! Use **parametrized queries** instead - they're safer and faster, too!

Comment: Please [edit] your title to be something meaningful. As it is now, it tells us nothing about the problem you're having, and will have no use in a search result by a future reader here. (While you're at it, you can type it without SHOUTING at us; it's totally unnecessary to type your question title in ALL CAPS, as it makes it harder to read, won't get you help faster, and quite frankly is extremely rude and annoying.)

Comment: The error message is fairly clear.  You're trying to insert the value of `NULL` into the `ID` column, which has been declared `NOT NULL`.

Comment: @KenWhite Is it OK now ?

Comment: @Raj: Yes, much better. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Somebody has down voted my question. Never mind. I think NOBODY IS 100% PERFECT IN THIS WORLD. If I do not know anything, is that my fault? Is Mr. Down Voting person 100% perfect ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line here:

```
.Append("CONTACT_NOS,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_TIME) VALUES(NULL,")
```

You are trying to insert `NULL` in a column which does not accept `NULLS`.

The ID column is set to auto increment (`IDENTITY (1,1)`).

Just leave that column out of the query parameters (it will automatically increment) and your query should be fine.

**SUGGESTION**: Use a parameterized query. It is a much more cleaner and optimized way of querying a database. It has plenty of advantages (which you can read yourself, I won't shed light on them here).

Also, you don't need to use append on every line. Its just *bad coding and quite irritating to read*!!! Also, code like this is *extremely unlikely to get through any round of code review.*

***EDIT:***

```
   INSERT INTO ADDRESS_BOOK(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, CONTACT_NOS, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_TIME)  VALUES('FirstName', 'LastName', '1234567890', 'SomeName', '2014-01-01 12:15:17.227')
```

Note that I have not mentioned the column `ID` at all here. When this statement will execute, the table containing this row will automatically have the `ID` value.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For your information, I always use MySQL for my application's backend. But this time, for client's requirement, I am using SQL Server. I use `NULL` for AutoIncrement in MySQL Table. Therefore I use the same here. Please tell me `How should I leave that column out of the query ?`. I never used `parametrized queries`. Is there any example (Code Block) having `identity` and `timestamp` ?

Comment: @Raj See the edit. You should frame your query as such.

Comment: Tried this but SQL Server is giving error `Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'ADDRESS_BOOK' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON`

Comment: @Raj By default, when a column is set to `IDENTITY`, it auto-increments the value for each row. So, you don't need to specify it explicitly. BUT let's say, *there is a case where you actually do want to set the ID value **manually instead of automatically***, then you'd make use of `IDENTITY_INSERT ON`. So naturally, when you do make use of it, you will have to explicitly specify the value of the `ID` column. Hope this clears the confusion :)

Comment: I am understanding the problem, but the real problem is I do not know the solution. When I am trying to insert it automatically, error shows `String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.`

Answer (score 2):

You have more than 1 issue going on here. The timestamp datatype (aka rowversion) is NOT a datetime datatype. Please read about that here. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

Secondly as others have pointed out your code is wide open to sql injection. You really should use a stored procedure for this type of thing.

Here is how I would write this, including the ddl with proper datatypes.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ADDRESS_BOOK] 
(
   [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
   [FIRST_NAME] [varchar] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
   [LAST_NAME] [varchar] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
   [CONTACT_NOS] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
   [MODIFIED_BY] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
   [MODIFIED_TIME] [timestamp] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

create procedure Address_Book_Insert
(
    @FName varchar(10)
    , @LName varchar(10)
    , @Contact_NOS varchar(50)
    , @Modified_By varchar(20)
    , @Modified_Time datetime
) as
    INSERT ADDRESS_BOOK
    (
        FIRST_NAME
        , LAST_NAME
        , CONTACT_NOS
        , MODIFIED_BY
        , MODIFIED_TIME
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @FName
        , @LName
        , @Contact_NOS
        , @Modified_By
        , @Modified_Time
    )

go
```

Then this is very simple. You change up your code to use a stored procedure, establish the parameters and execute the stored procedure. You will have easy separation of logic and data, your code will be much safer and it is a lot easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use SQL injection, it is easy to make a breach on your program.
Also, do not send a null value for ID, make sure to autoincrement by using IDENTITY (1,1)
I suggest using Stored Procedure for what are you doing... like this:

---

**ON SQL:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE '<schemaname>.InsertOnAddressBook'
(
--this is the arguments/parameters you should pass to the stored procedure
@TbFName varchar(30), --remember, this limit of varchar can be changed as you wish
@TbLName varchar(30),
@TbContactNos varchar(30),
@TbUser varchar(20)
)

AS

BEGIN
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ADDRESS_BOOK ON
INSERT INTO ADDRESS_BOOK
(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,CONTACT_NOS,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_TIME) 
VALUES(@TbFName, @TbLName, @TbContactNos, @TbUser, NULL) 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT ADDRESS_BOOK OFF
END
```

---

**ON VB.NET SIDE:**

```
cmd.CommandText = "<schemaname>.InsertOnAddressBook"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TbFName",TbFName.text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TbLName",TbLName.text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TbContactNos",TbContactNos.text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TbUser",TbUser.text)
```

---

Security wise, the stored Procedure is much safer to execute from your code behind!

Comment: Hi, This is the first time, I am going to use `Stored Procedure`. Let me try first. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `IDENTITY_INSERT` is set to `ON` then we have to specify the `Explicit value` for the `IDENTITY` column. Otherwise it will give the **error**:

> Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'TableName' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON`.

On the other hand:

> Just leave that column out of the query parameters (it will automatically increment) and your query should be fine.

Implementing the above statement from @Satwik Nadkarny, I found my answer.

**SOLUTION:**

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
With sb
    '.Append("SET IDENTITY_INSERT ADDRESS_BOOK ON ") '<-- No need to set it ON if we do not specify the Explicit value.
     .Append("INSERT INTO ADDRESS_BOOK(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,") '<-- I leaved the ID column out of the query
     .Append("CONTACT_NOS,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_TIME) VALUES(NULL,")
     .Append("'" & TbFName.Text & "','" & TbLName.Text & "','" & TbContactNos.text & "','" & TbUser.Text & "','" & MODIFIED_TIME & "')")
    '.Append(" SET IDENTITY_INSERT ADDRESS_BOOK OFF") '<-- No need to set it OFF
End With
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

**SQL:**

```
"INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4) VALUES(FIELD2_DATA,FIELD3_DATA,FIELD4_DATA)"
```

In the above SQL query statement `FIELD1` is the `ID` auto-increment Identity(1,1) field which I left out of the query. Besides, I have to learn *Query Parameterization* as I never used this.

---

Finally, it would be helpful for me to know why I have been down-voted.

Thanks @Satwik for your idea. It helped me a lot.